# Build "Rock, Paper, Scissors" in code codecademy

Tags: javascript

I learn basic JS using the codeacademy.

I am in step 6 and 7 of "Rock, Paper, Scrissors"

```
https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-Bthev-mskY8/1/2?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661

https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-Bthev-mskY8/1/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661
```

I have wrote the following code for the step 6 but it is wrong it gives me the following error

```
Oops, try again. Your code returned 'paper wins' instead of 'rock wins' when the inputs are rock and scissors

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if(choice1 === choice2) {
return "The result is a tie!";
}
else if(choice1 === "rock") {

        if (choice2 === "scrissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
}
};
console.log(compare('rock','scrissors'));
console.log(compare('rock','rock'));
console.log(compare('scissor','scissor'));
console.log(compare('paper','paper'));
console.log(compare('rock','paper'))
```

and it accept it as right answer in step 7.

What is going wrong with it?

Update the code:

```
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if(choice1 === choice2) {
return "The result is a tie!";
}
else if(choice1 === "rock") {

        if (choice2 === "scrissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
}
};
console.log(compare('rock','scrissors'));
console.log(compare('rock','rock'));
console.log(compare('rock','paper'))
```

Comment: `scrissors` should be `scissor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated: Ensure you spell it only: scissors not scrissors. CodeAcademy will use internal validation tools to check your result and if you don't spell it correctly the tool will fail because you're not handling the input that they've told you to handle!

Spelling mistake:

```
if (choice2 === "scrissors") { ... }

console.log(compare('rock','scrissors'));
console.log(compare('scissor','scissor'));
```

Comment: Ensure you spell it only: scissors not scrissors. CodeAcademy will use internal validation tools to check your result and if you don't spell it correctly the tool will fail because you're not handling the input that they've told you to handle!

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

var compare = function(choice1,choice2)

{

```
if(choice1 === choice2)
{
    return ("The result is a tie!");
}
else if(choice1 === "rock")
{
    if(choice2 === "scissors")
    {
        return ("rock wins");
    }
    else
    {
        return("paper wins");
    }
}
```

};

The program you posted has spelling mistake on the line 
if (choice2 === "scrissors") { ... }

Try changing it to scissors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how you can make it work:

```
<h1 id="title">Javascript  "Rock, Paper, Scrissors"</h1>
<select id="choice1">
  <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
  <option value="rock">Rock</option>
  <option value="paper">Paper</option>
  <option value="scissors">Scissors</option>
</select>
<select id="choice2">
  <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
  <option value="rock">Rock</option>
  <option value="paper">Paper</option>
  <option value="scissors">Scissors</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" id="byBtn" value="Compare" onclick="compare()"/>


function compare(){
   var choice1 = document.getElementById('choice1').value;
   var choice2 = document.getElementById('choice2').value;
   if(choice1==='base' || choice2==='base')
   {
       alert('Select an option for both inputs!');
       return;
   }
   if(choice1 === choice2) {
    alert("The result is a tie!");
    }
    else if(choice1 === "rock") {

            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                alert("Rock wins");
            }
            else {
                alert("Paper wins");
            }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "paper") {

            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                alert("Scissors wins");
            }
            else {
                alert("Paper wins");
            }
    }
    else if(choice1 === "scissors") {

            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                alert("Rock wins");
            }
            else {
                alert("Scissors wins");
            }
    }
}
```

As Neil told you it was a tippo mistake. I made an example in Fiddle so you can check it and use it as u like.

Nelson Parra.

[Example rock, paper and scissors](https://jsfiddle.net/nkkmLcgs/1/)